# Sed subexpressions not working as expected

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to make a simple wikitext parser using sed/bash. When I run

```
echo "London has [[public transport]]" | sed s/\\[\\[[A-Za-z0-9\ ]*\\]\\]/link/
```

it gives me `London has link`
but when I try to use marked subexpressions to get the contents of the brackets using

```
sed s/\\[\\[\([A-Za-z0-9\ ]*\)\\]\\]/\1/
```

it just gives me `London has [[public transport]]`

Answer (score 2):

That's because the regex doesn't match.

Since you're not surrounding your sed expression in quotes, you have to double-escape slashes for the shell - that's why you have `\\[` instead of `\[`.

Now in `sed` default regex (basic regular expressions), capturing brackets are denoted by `\(` and `\)` in regex. Since you're typing this into the shell without surrounding with quote marks, you need to *escape* the backslash. And since bash interprets brackets, you have to escape them too:

```
echo "London has [[public transport]]" | sed s/\\[\\[\\\([A-Za-z0-9\ ]*\\\)\\]\\]/\\1/
```

I **strongly recommend** you just enclose your sed expression in single quotes for ease of writing:

```
echo "London has [[public transport]]" | sed 's/\[\[\([A-Za-z0-9\ ]*\)\]\]/\1/'
```

Much easier right?

Comment: please forgive my ignorance, tried it in quotes and it worked. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "London has [[public transport]]" | sed 's@[[][[]\([A-Za-z0-9\ ]*\)[]][]]@\1@'
```

**output**

```
London has public transport
```

works on my machine.

I hope this helps.